# Why do we have plugins in android gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What does plugins in `build.gradle` do?
Why in project gradle I have these plugins

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
```

}

But in module I have these

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to gradle docs: [Using gradle plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html)

> Applying a plugin to a project allows the plugin to extend the project’s capabilities such as:  Apply specific configuration (e.g. add organizational repositories or enforce standards)

In this case you can set the gradle config for all your modules in your project level `build.gradle (Project: YourApp)`. More specifically you are adding Android Gradle Plugin version `7.2.1`:

```
    plugins {
     id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false       <---- Here
     id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    }
```

Also you use `apply false` syntax to tell Gradle not to apply the plugin to the current project and then use the plugins {} block without the version in subprojects' build scripts:

Reference: [Applying external plugins with same version to subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl)

Finally you can use in your module level `build.gradle (Module: app)` without its corresponding version:

```
    plugins {
      id 'com.android.application'        <----- Here
      id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    }
```